# Two errors while running Caffe

Tags: python, deep-learning, caffe

I've installed Caffe on my Ubuntu 14.04 machine. the `make runtest` runs perfectly fine with 581 tests passed. I'm trying to work with the command line and python interface and getting the following two errors:

1. **Command Line Interface:** When I try to run the command `caffe`, I'm getting the following error:

   ```
   No command 'caffe' found, did you mean: Command 'caff' from package 
    'signing-party' (universe)
   caffe: command not found
   ```
2. **Python Interface:** When I run the command `make pycaffe`, I'm getting the following error:

   ```
   CXX/LD -o python/caffe/_caffe.so python/caffe/_caffe.cpp
   python/caffe/_caffe.cpp:9:31: fatal error: numpy/arrayobject.h: No such file 
   or directory
   #include <numpy/arrayobject.h>
                                 ^
   compilation terminated.
   make: *** [python/caffe/_caffe.so] Error 1
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that numpy is installed correctly and the path is mentioned to detect the newly installed library. The [steps](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/installation.html#prerequisites) are provided in Caffe website itself.

For the 'Caffe' command to work, you will have to step into the folder where the 'Caffe' executable is created and then try running the executable through the terminal.

Comment: Thanks Anoop. It turns out numpy wasn't installed in the default Python on my machine. The Caffe command is still not working. However, I'm using Anaconda to run Python right now, and it all works out just fine.

I'm having issues with creating a LMDB data file to be run with Caffe though. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30769048/error-in-creating-lmdb-database-file-in-python-for-caffe) is the link to the question. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the second problem you had, I had the same problem, I solved uncommenting this line inside the Makefile.config:

```
# Decomment le line uncommented below:
# Homebrew installs numpy in a non standard path (keg only)
PYTHON_INCLUDE += $(dir $(shell python -c 'import numpy.core; print(numpy.core.__file__)'))/include
# PYTHON_LIB += $(shell brew --prefix numpy)/lib
```