# Error in creating LMDB database file in Python for Caffe

Tags: python, numpy, anaconda, caffe, lmdb

I'm trying to create an LMDB data base file in Python to be used with Caffe according to [this](http://deepdish.io/2015/04/28/creating-lmdb-in-python/) tutorial. The commands `import numpy as np` and `import caffe` run perfectly fine. However, when I try to run `import lmdb` and `import deepdish as dd`, I'm getting the following errors:

```
    >>> import lmdb
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    ImportError: No module named lmdb
    >>> import deepdish as dd
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    ImportError: No module named deepdish
```

I'm running Python 2.7.9 through Anaconda 2.2.0 (64-bit) on Ubuntu 14.04. While installing the dependencies for Caffe according to [this](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/install_apt.html) page, I've already installed the lmdb package through `sudo apt-get install liblmdb-dev`.

Any ideas why this error might be occuring?

Comment: you seem to have path definition issues. please check you PATH variable and verify that it indeed points to the location of the lmdb package

Comment: When I do `echo $PATH`, it returns the following: `/home/pras/anaconda/bin:$/usr/include:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games`. When I do `dpkg -L liblmdb-dev`, I get these:

`/.
/usr
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblmdb.a
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/liblmdb-dev
/usr/share/doc/liblmdb-dev/copyright
/usr/include
/usr/include/lmdb.h
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblmdb.so
/usr/share/doc/liblmdb-dev/changelog.Debian.gz`

Now, which of these should I add to $PATH?

Comment: Well, I tried to follow instructions as mentioned [here](https://lmdb.readthedocs.org/en/release/#installation-unix). `pip install lmdb` seemed to do the trick!

Comment: You should post this as an answer

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, the `apt-get install liblmdb-dev` might work with bash (in the terminal) but apparently it doesn't work with Anaconda Python. I figured Anaconda Python might require it's own module for lmdb and I followed [this](https://lmdb.readthedocs.org/en/release/#installation-unix) link. The Python installation for lmdb module can be performed by running the command `pip install lmdb` in the terminal. And then `import lmdb` in Python works like a charm!

The above installation commands may require sudo.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Anaconda, then this can solve your problem (it worked for me):

```
conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/dougal lmdb
```

Comment: Yields 404 error

Answer (score 1):

For Anaconda users, installing `python-lmdb` package from `conda-forge` should fix the `lmdb` import error:

```
conda install -c conda-forge python-lmdb
```

This was tested on `conda 4.5.11` on an `lxc`-containerized system running `Ubuntu 18.04`.

Note that there is a `conda` package named `lmdb` (without `python-`), installable via:

```
conda install -c conda-forge lmdb
```

that does not fix the import error.